# Clock & Date won't show up on boot sometimes in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10

[image]

Just like you can see in the screenshot above, sometimes the clock & date won't show up on boot. I have to log off to make it appear again.

Is that because I have a custom-time format in dconf editor ( %a, %d. %h  %H:%M ) ?

Answer (score 1):

**This is a temporary fix.** You have to repeat it every time you login and the clock does not show.

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
killall unity-panel-service
```

This will reinitialize the top panel and the clock will show up.

Comment: Yes. But the problem it's still there... I think this happen when I shutdown the computer by terminal using sudo shutdown -h +time, I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I used to have this problem. But I have not seen it recently. Is your system up to date?

Comment: Sure. I've just checked.